# How to read each element from a TextFile

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

```
Server_Name                                 Process_Name                               Server_Status                              Process_Available                         
-----------                                 ------------                               -------------                              -----------------                         
FILESTORAGE1                                  notepad                                    Online                                     No                                        
FILESTORAGE1                                  explorer                                   Online                                     Yes                                       
FILESTORAGE1                                  Sampler                                    Online                                     No                                        
FILESTORAGE1                                notepad                                    Online                                     No                                        
FILESTORAGE1                                explorer                                   Online                                     Yes                                       
FILESTORAGE1                                Sampler                                    Online                                     Yes                                       
FILESTORAGE1                                     notepad                                    Offline                                    No                                        
FILESTORAGE1                                     explorer                                   Offline                                    No                                        
FILESTORAGE1                                     Sampler                                    Offline                                    No
```

My file looks like this.

I want to get each element from my file and create an HTML file (from this TXT)

```
 $bodyFromFile = Get-Content "$PSScriptRoot\data.txt"
 $bodyString = $bodyFromFile | ConvertTo-Html
```

Unfortunately the contents of bodyString looks like it's legitimate HTML. The data from the file isn't in the variable.

Comment: Although the columns DO NOT line up here in this post. They are perfectly aligned in the actual TXT file

Comment: Do you control the creation of the text file? Putting it into an easier format to parse would be handy if possible. What do you want the html output to look like? Were you wanting to put it in an html table or something?

Comment: Do you need it to be in an HTML table?  If you are just displaying it, a super easy way would be to use `"<pre>" + $bodyFromFile + "</pre>"`

Comment: Yes I control the creation of the PSObject. I used Out-String and Out-File to create a txt file. I couldn't figure out how to use the Object directly. Ultimately the data will be used as an HTML body to be sent as email. I know we can use <pre> but I want the certain lines to be with red color if specific conditions are met. (Like Server is offline or if a process is not running.

Comment: You could persist the object to a file using Export-CliXml, and then when you want to generate your html file, just us Import-CliXml to create the object again, then you can use the object instead of parsing a plain text file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't convert your objects to a string when you want the end result to be tabular HTML output. Instead of

```
... | Out-String | Out-File "$PSScriptRoot\data.txt"
$bodyFromFile = Get-Content "$PSScriptRoot\data.txt"
$bodyString = $bodyFromFile | ConvertTo-Html
```

do something like this:

```
$table = ... | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment
$bodyString = "<body>$table</body>"
```

Comment: How would I be able to tell which "rows" contain "Offline" or "No". I want those rows to have a yellow background and text color text (so it stands out)

Comment: That is a different question and should be asked as such. Please do not move the target.

Comment: What does the -Fragment switch do?? I didn't use that when I tried to convert to Html

Comment: It converts the input to an HTML fragment (basically just a table), not an entire HTML page (headers and all).